# One handler for several events of different classes?

Tags: c#

I want to create a program that will draw a circle at the cursor position when it is moved.
I tried to create a method that will be an event handler for MouseEventHandler and PaintEventHandler, but I got the error cs0123. How to fix it, and is it even possible?
My code:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3)
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(My_func);//cs0123
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(My_func);//cs0123
    }

private void My_func(object sender, PaintEventArgs pe, MouseEventArgs me)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawEllipse(pen, pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position), 3, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pop in random arguments to eventhandlers with fixed signatures. Both of them expect 2 arguments only, [`PaintEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventhandler?view=net-5.0)  [`MouseEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler?view=net-5.0) so they can't be handled by a method which expects three arguments.

Either create two different eventhandlers, one for each event.

```
pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pehandler);
pictureBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(mehandler);

private void mehandler(object sender,  MouseEventArgs args) {
   ...
}

private void pehandler(object sender,  PaintEventArgs args) {
   ...
}
```

Or create a more generic one, which fits the signature

```
private void myfunc(object sender,  EventArgs args) {
   if (args is PaintEventArgs) { 
     //do something with the args
   }
   else if (args is MouseEventArgs { 
     //do something with the args
   }
}
```